# How to ignore files with invalid schema Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure Data Factory. Currently, I am trying to copy some data from files in blob storage to Azure Data Explorer.

The pipeline reads multiple files from a specific cosmos root directory and copies the data to ADE. Currently, the pipeline successfully handles the copy activities. I now want to add a validation component so that the pipeline only reads files with the correct schema and ignores the rest of the files.

The schema is as follows: Name, Type, Value, Date.

The pipeline itself should not fail/stop if the files are of invalid type or schema, it should just skip them and continue on with the rest of the files.

What component can I use for this validation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can use `ForEach` activity to achieve this requirement. The **ForEach activity** (in this case) can be used to copy each source file into destination. In case the schema don't match, the copy activity usually fails.
- But when a copy activity inside foreach fails, the pipeline execution does not fail/stop. It throws an error for that particular copy activity that fails, but it continues the execution of copy activity for remaining files.

Look at the following demonstration for clear understanding.

- The following are the files I am using for sample. The file `sample_3.csv` does not match the schema of my destination table.

[image]

- I used `Get Metadata` activity to get files names of the above files using `child items` field list. I passed these values to ForEach as `@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems`.

[image]

- Inside Foreach, I have a copy activity along with `wait` activity (wait executes only if copy activity fails)

[image]

- When I execute this pipeline, it completes successfully without any errors. The following is the debug output.

[image]

- The third iteration of copy activity fails as `sample_3.csv` has incorrect schema. And yet the pipeline runs successfully without failing.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

- Mapping need not be specified in copy activity.
  [image]

Comment: thanks! Quick follow-up question, for this I need to set the mapping explicitly in CopyData Activity, correct?

Comment: Hey @hachimanhikki, there is no need to specify mapping. The columns from each file will be taken as is from the source files (inside foreach) and mapped to destination. If they don't match, the copy activity for that particular file fails.